# Is there any particular advantage of using Selenium PageFactory class for C#.net

Tags: java, c#, selenium, pageobjects

I have used the PageFactory class in Java for my automated tests and found it a bit convenient as compared to the plain POM approach due to the extra features it provides.

But now I have to write them using C# and while googling about it, I found that the C# implementation of PageFactory class does not provide those extras. To be specific they are:

1) PageFactory.InitElements method does not return a Page Object as in Java. You have to return it separately.

2) The fallback mechanism of ID to Name. If any element cannot be found using the mentioned ID then PageFactory in Java automatically fall back to Name. In C# you have to explicitly define `How=How.Name` for this to happen.

3) The Java implementation can locate the element even without the FindsBy attribute but this isn’t the case for C#.

So I was wondering if there are any other reasons due to which it would still be worthwhile to use PageFactory implementation for C#.

BTW, source of above info that I found through google is [here](http://relevantcodes.com/pageobjects-and-pagefactory-design-patterns-in-selenium/).